# Searching a Custom Catalog on Network Share

Tags: c#, windows, indexing

We have a network server with 7 shares and millions of files of all types.  We created a custom catalog (SERVER_INDEX) so that we can search specifically for PDF files across several of these shares.  We had been using the IXSSO component to perform these searches but this no longer works in Win7 after update 2698365 is installed.  I can install the Hotfix from Microsoft but I want a solution that will work now and in the future.

I have researched the Microsoft documentation for searching the SYSTEMINDEX. This works well when searching on C: but returns no rows when directed to the network share.  The main document I used is "Using SQL and AQS Approaches to Query the Index (Windows)"

The query command string:

```
@"SELECT Top 5 System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX
 WHERE SCOPE='file:c:/users/halw/desktop' AND system.filename LIKE '%pdf' ";
```

returns exactly what is asked for.

Is it possible to use this syntax to query a custom index server catalog on a network share instead of SYSTEMINDEX?  I tried using the name of the catalog prefixed with the server name in every format I could imagine.  System.Data.dll returned "Unspecified error" in all cases.

Is ISearchQueryHelper a viable alternative?  I tried to install the SearchAPI.tlb from the Win7 SDK (v7.1A) using TlbImp.exe (from v7.0A. v7.1A did not have the exe.) but I could not register the resulting dll (regsvr32 said it had no entry point; probably a versioning issue but I don't know.  ).